# How to pass variable for dropping table execution in Python's MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, connection

With this code I tried to delete a table if it exists. But I need to do it via passing
a variables.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
conn = mdb.connect(host='db01.myhost.co.nl,
                        user='pdbois',
                        passwd='triplex',
                        db='myxxx')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Without passing variables this works OK!
#cursor.execute("""drop table if exists testtable""")

# But this break
table_name = "testtable"
cursor.execute("""drop table if exists %s""",(table_name))
conn.close()
```

But why the way I do it above breaks by giving this error?

```
  File "test_mysql.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "test_mysql.py", line 59, in main
    create_table()
  File "test_mysql.py", line 25, in create_table
    cursor.execute("""drop table if exists %s""",(table_name))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''testtable'' at line 1")
```

What's the right way to do it?

**Update:**
Another problem is to create a table via parameter.

```
 sql = "create table %s(
             first_name char(20) not null,
             last_name char(20))" % mdb.escape_string(table_name)

 cursor.execute(sql)

 It gives `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot parameterize the table name, use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) and escape the value manually:

```
cursor.execute("drop table if exists %s" % mdb.escape_string(table_name))
```

Comment: thanks. Another problem is parameterizing for creating table. See my update. How can I do it properly?

Comment: @pdubois this is because you are having a multi-line string, but you are still using single quotes. You need to use `"""` instead of `"`.